# Rust: File read error: 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "failed to fill whole buffer" })'

Tags: file, serialization, io, rust

I'm trying to write some game data to a file, and then read it back. The data is stored in a Vector of Structs. Writing the data to file works fine using serialize and bincode, but reading back is failing.

```
    // Try to save the data. (Works)
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(File::create("sector.dat").unwrap());
    serialize_into(&mut f, &sector_vector).unwrap();

    // Try to read the data (Fails with "failed to fill whole buffer" error)
    let mut read_sector_vector: Vec<Sector::Sector> =
        deserialize_from(BufReader::new(File::open("sector.dat").unwrap())).unwrap();
    read_sector_vector[0].displaysector();
```

I can't figure it out, and I don't know enough about rust to work out what I'm doing wrong. It seems to be a problem (from what I have read) about the BufReader not knowing the length of the data? But I don't know the length of the Vector (or at least I will not when I read the data for real in a different executable)

Comment: How should we know ? did you close your file before reopen it ? please read about [rust info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and provide an [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. I needed to drop the file because it was still in scope. In hindsight, it makes perfect sense.